# Javascript array filter two searchbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include, tostring

How to filter array values dynamically with two string (searchboxes)? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
if (!!this.searchCompany.toLowerCase() || !!this.searchName.toLowerCase()) {
  this.filter = true
  this.newval = this.list.filter(post => {
    if (!!this.searchCompany.toLowerCase()) {
      return post.profile.company ? post.profile.company.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchCompany.toLowerCase()) : null
    } else if (!!this.searchName.toLowerCase()) {
      return post.profile.full_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchName.toLowerCase())
    } else {
      return post
    }
  })
```

**this.searchCompany** and **this.searchName** are the searchboxes in my form.

The array content of **this.list**

[image]

Comment: Please add your `input array`.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**

Here is your condition checking

```
if(!!this.searchCompany.toLowerCase())
```

It does not check whether the value is presented and in lower case. Firstly it will be transformed to lower case by String method and then cast to **boolean** type. As we know, empty string casts to boolean **FALSE** and any non empty string to **TRUE**. Moreover, you can get **TypeError** in case that `searchCompany` property is not presented in `this`.

Here small example snippet how you can search in array of objects

```js
const posts = [{
    company: 'Coca-Cola',
    name: 'Rocket'
  },
  {
    company: 'Pepsi-Cola',
    name: 'Groot'
  }
]
let form = document.forms['search-form']
let resultBox = document.querySelector('#result-box')
let searchButton = document.querySelector('#search')

searchButton.addEventListener('click', doSearch, false)

function searchPost(parameter, searchString) {
  return posts.find(post => post[parameter].toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()))
}

function isFormEmpty() {
  return [...form.children].filter(e => e.type === 'text').reduce((r, c) => r && !c.value.length, true)
}

function doSearch() {
  if (isFormEmpty(form)) {
    e.preventDefault()
    return false
  }
  let searchNameEl = form.querySelector('[name="searchName"]')
  let searchCompanyEl = form.querySelector('[name="searchCompany"]')
  let searchParam = searchCompanyEl.value.length ? 'company' : 'name'
  let searchText = searchCompanyEl.value.length ? searchCompanyEl.value : searchNameEl.value
  let post = searchPost(searchParam, searchText)
  resultBox.textContent = JSON.stringify(post)
}
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
}

.result {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <label>Search company</label>
  <input type="text" name="searchCompany" />

  <label>Search name</label>
  <input type="text" name="searchName" />

  <button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="result">
  <pre id="result-box"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: `!!this.searchCompany.toLowerCase()` this is to check if it has value and should be in a lowercase.